# Can I show only the tag of citation in WORD?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a list of citations in WORD.
For example, the first one has the tag "1".
Can I show only the tag in the document?
For example:
"The method is shown in [1]...."

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Super User.

Look into the Endnotes feature on the References tab. Is this what you are looking for?

You can add additional cross-references to things listed in Endnotes.

Here is a [temporary link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/48d65gnces7t3l7/deleteme%20endnotes.docx?dl=0) to a document that does this.

Comment: This one is adding the notes to the end... I need it In the line of the text as I showed

Comment: What prevents you from doing that? If you do not want the superscript, change the style for Endnote Reference. I added a link in my Answer to a document set up this way.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to put them in a specific page, without the line above them? For example, take the page with header "refs" and add them there?

Comment: You said you wanted Endnotes, which go to the end of the document or section, not on a specific page. If you want them at the bottom of the page, you would use a footnote. The line is intended to separate notes from the text body.  If you want a reference to text in the body of the document, you would use a cross-reference.